# VB.NET Sharing list of string everywhere

Tags: vb.net

So here's my code of list of string

```
Private Sub gen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles gen.Click
    Dim num As Decimal = 10000
                Dim i As Decimal = Decimal.One
                Do While (Decimal.Compare(i, num) <= 0)
                    Dim list3 As New List(Of String)

                    If crypto.Checked Then
                        list3.AddRange(Strings.Split("BTC eBTC cryptocurrency crypto currency blockchain wallet p2p Auroracoin Blackcoin Coinye Bitcoin Dash Decred Dogecoin DigitalNote Ehtereum Gridcoin Litecoin Mastercoin MazaCoin Monero Namecoin Nxt Peercoin Primecoin Ripple Titcoin Zerocoin Satoshi Stellar Shadow Lisk virtualcurrency virtualmoney steem NEM MaidSafeCoin Coins Mining MiningCoins Ghz Nxt Synereo DigixDAO Factom Waves Emercoin Bitshares Peerplays Stellar Btyecoin Siacoin Counterparty tther gamecredits xaurum bitcrystals storjcoinX SysCoin YbCoin AgorasTokens NameCoin NautilusCoin FedoraCoin Swiscoin SARCoin BitcoinDark VPNCoin SuperNET Omni DigiByte Blackcoin GridCoin Stratis IOCoin SolarCoin RubyCoin Rimbit FeatherCoin DNotes VeriCoin VCash HiCoin MonaCoin Expanse ShadowCash Voxels MintCoin EarthCoin Jinn BreakoutState Nexus Scotcoin Clams Primecoin Quark LBRY GlobalCurrency ReddCoin HitCoin Blocknet NAVCoin Radium Novacoin Worldcoin EvergreenCoin AuroraCoin SaluS Gulden DigitalNote CureCoin Obits AsiaCoin Vertcoin Rise Quora BoostCoin Startcoint ReeCoin MMNXT MegaCoin Adzcoin Pebblecoin NuBits Ixcoin XCurrency Virtacoin GoldCoin ProjectDecorum Bitshares BilShares BitBay HempCoin Crypti LIQUID Stress", " ", -1, CompareMethod.Binary))
                    End If

Loop
            End Using

        End If
End Sub
```

Now what i want is how can i share this "Dim list3 As New List(Of String)" in another button
like i have a button "Clear list"

```
Private Sub clear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles clear.Click
    list3.Clear()

End Sub
```

But when i declare "Dim list3 As New List(Of String)" in class and remove within "Do While (Decimal.Compare(i, num) <=0)" it will force stop

Comment: You make the list `Dim list3 As New List(Of String)` a member variable of your class and not a member of the function. Take a read of [Scope in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/scope)

Comment: This is what Resources are for

Comment: ps you made a typo in ethereum ;)

Comment: What's that loop for? Did you check what is doing? Also a complete waste, since you're recreating the List on each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim list3 As New List(Of String)

Private Sub gen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles gen.Click
    Dim num As Decimal = 10000
    Dim i As Decimal = Decimal.One
    Do While (Decimal.Compare(i, num) <= 0)
        list3 = New List(Of String)

        If crypto.Checked Then
            list3.AddRange(Strings.Split("BTC eBTC cryptocurrency crypto currency blockchain wallet p2p Auroracoin Blackcoin Coinye Bitcoin Dash Decred Dogecoin DigitalNote Ehtereum Gridcoin Litecoin Mastercoin MazaCoin Monero Namecoin Nxt Peercoin Primecoin Ripple Titcoin Zerocoin Satoshi Stellar Shadow Lisk virtualcurrency virtualmoney steem NEM MaidSafeCoin Coins Mining MiningCoins Ghz Nxt Synereo DigixDAO Factom Waves Emercoin Bitshares Peerplays Stellar Btyecoin Siacoin Counterparty tther gamecredits xaurum bitcrystals storjcoinX SysCoin YbCoin AgorasTokens NameCoin NautilusCoin FedoraCoin Swiscoin SARCoin BitcoinDark VPNCoin SuperNET Omni DigiByte Blackcoin GridCoin Stratis IOCoin SolarCoin RubyCoin Rimbit FeatherCoin DNotes VeriCoin VCash HiCoin MonaCoin Expanse ShadowCash Voxels MintCoin EarthCoin Jinn BreakoutState Nexus Scotcoin Clams Primecoin Quark LBRY GlobalCurrency ReddCoin HitCoin Blocknet NAVCoin Radium Novacoin Worldcoin EvergreenCoin AuroraCoin SaluS Gulden DigitalNote CureCoin Obits AsiaCoin Vertcoin Rise Quora BoostCoin Startcoint ReeCoin MMNXT MegaCoin Adzcoin Pebblecoin NuBits Ixcoin XCurrency Virtacoin GoldCoin ProjectDecorum Bitshares BilShares BitBay HempCoin Crypti LIQUID Stress", " ", -1, CompareMethod.Binary))
        End If

    Loop

End Sub

Private Sub clear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles clear.Click
    list3.Clear()

End Sub
```

End Class

I am sorry. I had forgotten to enable one instruction. Please, check the code and try again.
Happy coding!:)

Comment: so it means what i'm using loop need list of string to be there

Comment: One thing is to declare a variable and other thing is when you do an instance to start to use that variable. With: Dim list3 As New List(Of String) you declare a variable ; With: list3 = New List(Of String) you do a new instance of that variable which is ready to use. :)

Comment: @Sh4lltear If this answers your question, please accept the answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.